# How to convert collection of Objects to collection of custom types?

Tags: java, object, collections

I have :

```
List<Object[]>
```

Would like to convert to:

```
List<MyClass>
```

Obviously it possible iterate all list, but may be exists ready class for it?
Thanks.

Comment: You will need to cast each element so I don't see how you could avoid a loop...

Comment: To clarify, your first list contains Objects, not Object arrays, right?

Comment: This list received from db. List contains array of object. I am pretty sure about type of each element of array.

Comment: Apache Commons has `ListUtils.transformedList` but it doesn't support Generics. So I think you should write one and I think it's not so hard to do.

Comment: Guava has a generic Lists.transform, but it's really not appropriate for something like this.  The best solution is the most obvious one: just iterate.

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't a simple way to do this.  You'll have to do it "the normal way," by iterating through the input collection.